# Problemas con ajax.beginform y validacion del lado del cliente

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, mvc

Quiero hacer las validaciones del lado del cliente pero me encuentro con el siguiente problema. Si el modelo no es valido me retorna la vista con los mensajes de error en el `UpdateTargetId` del formulario, tal que así:

[image: Imagen de Ejemplo]

La parte del código del formulario sería el siguiente:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Estadistica",
                    new AjaxOptions
                    {
                        OnBegin = "onBegin",
                        OnComplete = "onComplete",
                        OnFailure = "onSuccess",
                        OnSuccess = "onFailure",
                        HttpMethod = "Post",
                        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                        UpdateTargetId = "dvAjaxFormResult"
                    }))
                {...}
```

El código del controlador es el siguiente:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (!(Session["Usuario"] is Usuario))
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
        }

        var modelo = new EstadisticaIndex
        {
            FechaDesde = DateTime.Now.Date,
            FechaHasta = DateTime.Now.Date,
            Regional = Funciones.ListaRegional()
        };
        return PartialView(modelo);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(EstadisticaIndex filtroEstadistica)
    {
        if (!(Session["Usuario"] is Usuario))
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
        }
        var modelo = new EstadisticaIndex
        {
            FechaDesde = DateTime.Now.Date,
            FechaHasta = DateTime.Now.Date,
            Regional = Funciones.ListaRegional()
        };

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return PartialView(modelo);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("EstadisticaConsecutivos", "Estadistica",filtroEstadistica);


    }
```

Comment: revisa muy bien tu hacia donde estas apuntado la respuesta, estas retornando tu vista completa donde probablemente tu solo busques retornar datos. Resiva espesificamente en el return de tu controlador, si es vista o el json de objetos

Comment: tienes dos metodos index que son inecesarios al final necesitas uno solo pues tu metodo es de tipo POST y estas llamando solo a ese. Te recomiendo que veas esta pregunta 78386 ponla en tu buscador. ahi pongo un ejemplo como el que necesitas. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instala el nuget microsoft.jquery.unobtrusive.ajax y llama tu formulario:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Estadistica", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "Post", UpdateTargetId = "dvAjaxFormResult", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }))
```

asegúrate de tener instalado y bien referenciado el paquete nuget y si puedes pon parte del código de tu controlador para ver si no tienes problemas en el. Saludos

Comment: Hola @Vicente Almea gracias por su tiempo ayuda, esta librería ya la estoy utilizando, ya agregue el código del controlador